# Change value of disabled checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

So I've run across a little snag.  I have a page where I have a checkbox being displayed but is disabled (the user can't change it's value due that it's DB driven).  Below this checkbox, I have an autocomplete field.  Should an item from the autocomplete come back, I need to be able to toggle the value of the disabled checkbox.  However, I'm unable to do so at this moment.

Here is my code so far.

View

```
...
<tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.IsSpecialOrder):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsSpecialOrder)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsSpecialOrder)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.ItemNumber):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @if (Model.Id > 0)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemNumber)
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemNumber)
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
...
$("#ItemNumber").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var itemNumber = $("#ItemNumber").val();
                //Get available Products based on search parameter and map data
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProductsByItemNumber", "PurchaseOrder")', { searchProduct: itemNumber }, function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        productData.push({ 'Id': data[i].Id, 'Name': data[i].Name, 'ItemNumber': data[i].ItemNumber, 'Description': data[i].Description,
                            'IsSpecialOrder': data[i].IsSpecialOrder
                        });
                    }
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.ItemNumber,
                            id: item.Id
                        };
                    }));
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.id == 0) {
                    //Do some house cleaning and alert user to mistake
                    alert("You must retry your search for a Product");
                    $("#Name").val("");
                    $("#ItemNumber").val("");
                    $(".ProductDescription").html("");
                    document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.IsSpecialOrder)").checked = false;
                    //$("#IsSpecialOrder").prop("checked", false);

                    return false;
                }

                //Record ProductId
                $("#ProductId").val(ui.item.id);

                //Fill RequestorExt with correct data
                var description = GetData(productData, ui.item.id, "desc");
                var name = GetData(productData, ui.item.id, "name");
                var isSpecialOrder = GetData(productData, ui.item.id, "is");
                $(".ProductDescription").html(description);
                $("#Name").val(name);
                document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.IsSpecialOrder)").checked = isSpecialOrder;
                //$("#IsSpecialOrder").prop("checked", isSpecialOrder);
            }
        });
...
</script>
```

From what I've been reading, disabled fields cannot be changed without enabling.  I'm guessing that is the only way to fix this but wanted to make sure first.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've been reading, disabled fields cannot be changed without
>   enabling. I'm guessing that is the only way to fix this but wanted to
>   make sure first. Any ideas?

Disabled fields can sure be changed [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETSyk/). Double check that you have the right value in your js code.

For reference (same code that's on fiddle):

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" id="chkbox"/>
<input type="button" value="Toggle" id="toggle"/>

var chkBox = $("#chkbox");
$("#toggle").click(function(){        
    if (chkBox.is(':checked')) {        
        chkBox.prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {        
        chkBox.prop('checked', true);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  The problem was the fact I was using @Html.DisplayFor.  When I switched to an input of checkbox type, it worked perfectly for me.  Stupid DisplayFor always seems to cause me issues anymore.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. I always do the html way, so UI people who scratch their head about razor syntax.

Comment: Lol, yeah.  Razor is nice and all but has some serious pitfalls they don't warn you about when working with jQuery/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if checkbox is enabled or disabled. You should remove `checked` attribute from checkbox instead of setting it's `checked` property to false, otherwise it will remain checked:

```
document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.IsSpecialOrder)").removeAttribute('checked');
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/izonur/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

disabled items are not submited by the form http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

you can have readonly items that are submited with the form (exactly the opposite of what you want)

I guess you are submitting form via a javascript somehow not properly. You must EXCLUDE disabled items from form when submitting, so it will work accordingly.

Comment: This sounds closer to what I was reading.  The checkbox is part of a form.  I'll try taking it out to see what happens.